# Mock a method and capture one of its output parameters after the execution

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock a member method `parseString` so that:

1. It keeps its original behaviour, that is, it returns its original method return value *and* fills the output parameter (`std::vector<std::string>& iReqs`) as the original method;
2. I can check one of its output parameter (`std::vector<std::string>& iReqs`)

There is probably an easy way to do it, but I didn't find a clean way so far .
What I got closest the most is the following, with GMock:

1. Use a lambda to mimic the original method behaviour
2. Use `SaveArgs` to store the parameter

The problem with this approach is that `SaveArgs` doesn't return any value, and it makes the test crash compiling in release mode. If I invert the two `DoAll` statements, `SaveArgs` is called before the method actually fills it, so it's meaningless. If I add the step 3. and modify a little the step 1.:

1. Use a lambda to mimic the original method behaviour *and* store the original return value;
2. Use `SaveArgs` to store the parameter;
3. Return the original return value;

Then it *seeems* to work, except for one case in my tests, so it looks there may be some *undefined behaviour* hidden in this *solution*.

Code snippet:

```
class FooMock : public Foo
{

public:

    FooMock() : Foo()
    {
        // By default, all calls are delegated to the real object.
        // Moreover, we capture intermediary object for testing purposes
        // We need to save _originalReturn otherwise we will have undef behaviour
        ON_CALL(*this, parseString).WillByDefault(DoAll(
            ([this](const std::string& iDoc,
                    std::vector<std::string>& iReqs) {
                        _originalReturn = this->Foo::parseString(iDoc, iReqs);
                        return _originalReturn;
                    }),
            SaveArg<1>(&_requests),
            Return(_originalReturn)
        ));
    }

    MOCK_METHOD2(parseString, bool (const std::string& iDoc,
                                    std::vector<std::string>& iReqs));

    virtual ~FooMock() = default;

    std::vector<std::string> _requests;

private:
    bool _originalReturn = false;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;

    virtual ~Foo() = default;

    bool execute( const std::string& iMessage ) { 
         // Calling parseString here
         return true; 
    }

protected:
    virtual bool parseString(const std::string& iMessage,
                             std::vector<std::string>& oBom){
         //Does something here
         return true;
    }        
};
```

In the GTest I should be able to do the following:

```
TEST_F( FooMockTest, basicRequest )
{
    std::string aString = "Something";

    FooMock uc;
    
    EXPECT_CALL(uc, parseString(_, _)).Times(1);

    EXPECT_TRUE(uc.execute(aString));

    // Test some property of the output parameter...
    ASSERT_EQ(1U, uc._requests.size());
   
}
```

Again, I can't find a way to concatenate the two behaviours I would like for my mocked member method, preserving its original behaviour and saving the args after its original execution.

I think my latest snippet is not safe and may hide some inconsistency (since I pass through an intermediate variable as Mocked class member field).

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: I would wish to help, but since the snippet is not a [mcve], I dont want to spend time on solving compiler errors. Particularly { has no matching token, Boo and b are undefined, missing included headers and using directives...

Comment: @S.M. thanks for your feedback. I updated the snapshot to have something coherent, sorry for the imprecision.  By the way, the snippet should compile (and it's not a compiling issue, rather a runtime one). The question is not completely clear, I agree, I tried to improve it.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood mock objects and the usage of gmock: `FooMock` can be used to replace `Foo` for the test but not to test it self, `ON_CALL` seems to be called in test cases.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I don't see any UB here. If you want to get help with that - create separate question.

About this one, I recommend for you to just use gMock matchers properly. Basically, you want some trivial thing, but you just using wrong tools for that. In your code you used placeholders in EXPECT_CALL instead of actual matchers:

```
EXPECT_CALL(uc, parseString(_, _)).Times(1);
```

Those placeholders must be used when you don't care which parameters was used during call. But you care about them and even created special field to compare them. So you just need to use proper matchers, in this case [Container matchers](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html#container-matchers) to validate what items was used during that call. In you snippet you are validating amount of items, it can be done with `SizeIs` matcher:

```
EXPECT_CALL(uc, parseString(_, SizeIs(1))).Times(1);
```

There are a lot of other pretty complex matchers which can help you to match parameters in any scenario. For example you want to ensure that when `parseString` was called second input parameter contains one string which has substring "MAD". It will looks like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(uc, parseString(_, Contains(HasSubstr("MAD")))).Times(1);
```

So my version for task described in question will looks like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;

    bool execute(const std::string& iMessage)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> Bom;
        Bom.push_back("first_item");
        return parseString(iMessage, Bom);
    }

protected:
    virtual bool parseString(const std::string& iMessage,
        std::vector<std::string>& oBom)
    {
        oBom.push_back("extra_item");
        return true;
    }
};

class FooMock : public Foo {

public:
    FooMock()
    {
        ON_CALL(*this, parseString).WillByDefault([this](const std::string& iDoc, std::vector<std::string>& iReqs) {
            return Foo::parseString(iDoc, iReqs);
        });
    }
    MOCK_METHOD2(parseString, bool(const std::string& iDoc, std::vector<std::string>& iReqs));
};

TEST(FooMockTest, basicRequest)
{
    std::string aString = "Something";

    FooMock uc;

    EXPECT_CALL(uc, parseString(aString, SizeIs(1))).Times(1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(uc.execute(aString));
}
```

In this case we will validate that `parseString` will be called once during call of `execute` method, it will receive same string which was passed to `execute` and vector with one item (in this case vector which contains "first_item" element).

Comment: Oh, I see! does it means that matchers are applied at the end of the call as well, I didn't know that, I thought it was just to validate the input parameters, not also the I/O params.

Comment: I think that I need to use the `OnChanged()` directive btw, to show I want to match the output parameter...

Comment: It doesn't work, as it's capturing the parameter *before* the execution og the method

Comment: If you want to test result of `parseString` method - just write simple test for that method. There will be no reason to use mocking in that case. My suggestion was inline to rational usage of mocking system.